I can't get rid off ^M with a custom function for putting in WSL
I am trying to write a function for putting copied text from Windows to WSL, but in-spite of my attempts, I cannot get rid of the ^M.
Here is my attempt:
  vim9script

  def WslPut(above: bool = false)
    var copied_text = systemlist('powershell.exe -NoProfile -ExecutionPolicy Bypass Get-Clipboard')
                     ->map((idx, val) => substitute(val, "\r", '', 'g'))
    var linenr = above ? line('.') - 1 : line('.')
    appendbufline(bufnr(), linenr, copied_text)
  enddef

  nnoremap "+p <scriptcmd>WslPut()<cr>
  nnoremap "+P <scriptcmd>WslPut(true)<cr>

When I use the mapping defined above, I still have the ^M in the put text.
Using gvim with the following:
VIM - Vi IMproved 9.1 (2024 Jan 02, compiled Jun 24 2024 00:58:28)
Included patches: 1-516
Compiled by runner@fv-az1428-633
Huge version with GTK3 GUI.  Features included (+) or not (-):

that includes +clipboard

Why do you need it in the first place? Vim (vim-gtk3) works well in WSL.

I need it because when I "+p I get ^M at the end of each line? (Using gvim, I update the main question).

%s/\r$// Why Powershell?!

powershell.exe Get-Clipboard is needed to get what is in the Windows clipboard. For example, if you copy some text from a web browser with ctrl-c on Windows, you have to retrieve it in some way. The problem is that the retrieved text is full of ^M.

There's a single clipboard for WinAPI, WSL/X11 and WSL/Wayland.

Although the tone is perhaps exaggerated, Matt’s comments seem intended to point out that there is a much simpler way to do all this: it would perhaps help to back up and explain your situation. There might be something misconfigured that, once fixed, will make your problem go away.

The same happen when I gvim --clean. So I don't know what is really going wrong. The simpler way I think it is to modify the function such that it reads from the register +, append lines and then run exe ":%s/\\r$//g", i.e. use the bruteforce method.

For those with my same issue, here is a solution that appears to work decently:
  def WslPut(above: bool = false)
    var start_linenr = above ? line('.') - 1 : line('.')
    var copied_text = split(getreg('+'), '\n')
    var end_linenr = start_linenr + len(copied_text)
    appendbufline(bufnr(), start_linenr, copied_text)
    silent! exe $":{start_linenr},{end_linenr}s/\\r$//g"
  enddef

  nnoremap "+p <scriptcmd>WslPut()<cr>
  nnoremap "+P <scriptcmd>WslPut(true)<cr>

You should have unnamedplus in the clipboard option. Now you can paste with "+p and "+P when in normal mode.
